# Rebase program with negative shift delta in IDA

Tags: ida

If a binary file is open with ROM starting at 0x10A000, how do I easily change the ROM starting address of the file to 0x109000? I always had to restart IDA to do it. I also tried to "rebase the program using shift delta" but I don't know how to use a negative shift delta, plus it's not automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebase it and choose a new **Image base** of `0x109000` instead of trying to specify a **Shift delta**.

Comment: Hello, by any chance, can this be automated using IDC?

Answer (score 3):

Look in IDA menu:

Edit->Segments->Rebase program.